# C++ - Windows Iot Core Remote Debugger - Debugger fails to start

Tags: c++, debugging, windows-10-iot-core

I just bought a Raspberry Pi 3 and I am trying to set-up and remotely debug an application on my Pi.

I've been doing some research and Microsoft has [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps) that the debugging authentication type "Universal" is used for iot devices. (When I use "Universal" I get an error when I try to debug)

Error:

```
Error DEP6953 : Failed to launch remote debugger with the following error: 'DEP6953 : Failed to launch remote debugger with the following error: 'Command failed: 0x800705b4'.'.    BackgroundApplication2
```

But if I change the Authentication to "No Authentication" the app successfully deploys to my Raspberry Pi but I am unable to actually debug it (halt at breakpoints, etc)

This is the error I get:
[image]

My Settings Currently:
[image]

So is there any way to step through my code on the Visual Studio as its executing on my PI? Do I need to download some extra stuff?

Comment: What's your Visual Studio version? Have you tried remove the port(8116) in Machine Name of the debugging setting?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I have with both Authentication types, it says "Remote Debugger does not appear to be running on Remote Computer" (When I turn on Remote Debugger on the IOT Core, it tells me to type in 192.168.1.143:8116.

But I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Comment: No need turning on Remote Debugger. Just reboot your Raspberry Pi and try with official sample [HelloBlinkyBackground](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/HelloBlinkyBackground/CPP) .

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio does not seem happy with launching msvscon.exe by user, either as DefaultAccount or not.

To solve your issue you can try the following two method:

1. Reboot the remote device.
2. Kill all msvsmon.exe processes in [Device Portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal) like this:

[image]

or execute this command in [PowerShell](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/powershell):

```
kill.exe msvsmon
```